# Capture when an email is actually sent

Tags: c++, outlook

I'm working on an application that captures some Outlook events. Is it possible to detect the event when an email is sent. I don't mean when the user clicks on "send" button but when the email is actually sent and is no more in the outbox. Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***

I managed to capture the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the sent mails folder. In order to check whether the last email added to the sent items folder is the one I'm interestd in I tried this :

```
STDMETHODIMP CItemsEventListener::HandleItemAdd(CString p_date, CString p_time)
{
    CComPtr<Outlook::_Application> spApplication;
    CComPtr<Outlook::_NameSpace> spSession;
    CComPtr<Outlook::MAPIFolder> spSentMailsFolder;
    CComPtr<Outlook::_Items> pSentboxItems;
    spSentMailsFolder->get_Items(&pSentboxItems);
    CComPtr<Outlook::_MailItem> pSentMail;
    pSentMail = pSentboxItems->GetLast();
    //do staff
    return S_OK;
}`
```

I'm getting compiler error :

```
error C2660: 'Outlook::_Items::GetLast' : the function doesn't take 0 arguments
```

Which argument should I pass to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailItem.Send and Application.ItemSend events occur before the message is actually sent.

To capture when a message is actually sent, use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dimtry, I never worked with Outlook Items events and folders, for other events such as SyncEvents and Application events I'm implementing IDispatch interface. The same approach would work for Items.ItemAdd event? IWhich steps should I follow. I searched for examples but I only found VB examples or Add-Ins ones however I'm developing a c++ separate application.

Comment: If you import the Outlook Object Model library, your should get the wrapper classes that expose the events. Otherwise you can do it the low level way (QI the object that raises events for IConnectionPointerContainer, call IConnectionPointerContainer::FindConnectionPoint passing the appropriate event dispinterfaace GUID, call IConnectionPointer::Advise passing your implementation of the IDispatch interface that will receive event notifications via IDispatch::Invoke)

Comment: Thanks @Dimtry, my life saver as usual :) you were of great help to me

Comment: re @Dmitry, I want to get the last item added to olFolderSentMail folder, please check my update.

Comment: Why do you need to use GetLast? the item in question will be passed to your ItemAdd event handler.

Comment: so, is it possible to get the conversation index or the enrty Id of that item in order to identify it?

Comment: Yes, but ItemAdd event passes the new Item as a Dispatch interface parameter. I am not sure why your event handler takes two strings as parameters.